# Async Storage is not persisting on app reload

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm wondering if you could help me figure out why my data doesn't persist when I reload my app in React Native using Async Storage. Here are my details:

React Native .61.2 / Using React Native Community – Async Storage / testing in XCode Simulator on iOS

When I initially set my data and then get it, I get the correct response. When I set my data, reload the app, and try to get my data again, it comes back as the letter "a".

Here's how I'm setting my data:

```
changeUsernameToLowercase = text => {
    var temp = text.toLowerCase();
    this.setState({email: temp});
    this._storeData('@email', temp);
  };

async _storeData(name, value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(name, value);
    } catch (error) {
      // Error saving data
      console.log('FAILING: ' + error);
    }
  }
```

And here's my JSX from my render that calls changeUsernameToLowercase:

```
 <TextInput
              onChangeText={text => this.changeUsernameToLowercase(text)}
              placeholder="Email address"
              value={this.state.email}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              type="password"
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                borderBottomColor: '#333',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}
            />
```

Here's how I'm getting my data:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._retrieveEmail().then(response => {
      console.log('My log:' + response); //returns letter a on reload
      return response;
    });
  }

async _retrieveEmail() {
    try {
      var email = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@email');
      console.log('MY EMAIL LOG:' + email); //returns letter a on reload
      return email;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

It's possible I'm misunderstanding how persistent storage works, but I thought it was so the data persists on something like a reload?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It should work like you expect. Try doing some debugging, e.g. add `console.log('reading', await AsyncStorage.getItem(name)` in your `_storeData` function to see what is actually being stored

Comment: When I add reading/saving console logs, I get the same results as what I am getting when I'm retrieving it in my componentDidMount step: when I go through the log in step and store then retrieve my email address, I can retrieve it. When I reload my app after I'm already logged in (which doesn't bring me through the login step that sets my value, but I believe it should still be present because of persistent storage), I get back the letter "a". (My email address I'm using is 1@2.com, so nothing to do with the letter a.)

Comment: I didn't understand tbh, do 'saving' and 'reading' show the same thing or not? From the code you provided, saving happens every time you enter something in textinput, so you should get 'reading' with what you have entered every keystroke. Is that the case?

Comment: Yep, saving and reading show the same thing. You’re also correct that saving happens on every keystroke, WHEN you hit the login screen. Here’s my flow: (1) Login with email/password MongoDB Stitch login. When I type my email in, it stores it in async storage. 
(2) On successful login, I’m granted an access token and returned an “authenticated user” object, which I use to change the state of my app to tell it to skip the login screen next time.

Comment: (3) At this point, I am manually reloading the iOS simulator to test the async storage. When it reloads, I do an "initializeDefaultAppClient” on Stitch to check if I’m logged in. It returns the authenticated user, which causes me change my app state and skip the login screen (so I am not setting the async storage again at this point). 
(4) Try to access the email address I had stored in async storage before the reload. Get the letter “a” returned.

Comment: AsyncStorage should literally just read whatever you wrote last on that key. Are you sure you don't have any hanging .setItem calls anywhere? Try changing `'@email'` key in your code to something else and run it again

Comment: It's a bug with `@react-native-community/async-storage` > `1.2.4`: https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/86

Answer (score 0):

In my iOS React Native app, AsyncStorage was not persisting on refresh because I was also using **Firebase Authentication**.

Firebase Authentication uses AsyncStorage from `react-native` under the hood. This poses conflicts if you are also using `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`.

The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847#issue-452686444).